# User not in a room receive messages from users in a room - Socket.io - Emitter

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, long-polling

I am using the socket.io emitter and the socket.io redis component.

This is my code on the server which occurs when the user wants to start chat with others in a room :

```
emitter.to(roomId).emit('someonejoined', data);
socket.join(roomId);
```

The problem is that if the person doesnt click on the button "start chat" on a particular room but successfully connected to the server, he/she can get the messages being sent by the people on that chat room.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Provide more information - what's `room`, what's `objAnnounced` - we have absolutely no clue what's going on, except "it's not working"..

Comment: I suspect the server-side code for broadcasting a user's message is emitting to the default room. Could you post your server-side code?

Comment: room is room id, its not that something is not working, as I said until a peer joins a room he/she will get all messages being emitted by the socket.io-emitter